# Expandable Image header with string items

Tags: android, expandablerecyclerview

[Layout example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYlVm.png)

I want to achieve something like that shown in the picture without using any external libraries. I have an ArrayList with objects and each of the objects has a String for the image url and an ArrayList for the string data.

For example, an ArrayList Object:

```
ArrayList<MyObject> object = new ArrayList<>();
```

is given as a parameter to the recyclerview adapter.

```
object=[String urlImage,ArrayList<String> data].
```

How can I achieve this with viewtypes? What is the condition of position or something like that?

Comment: Expandable list view can be used for this.

Comment: When user click on text - Did you want that the in the place of textview show Image ?    (means onClick replace text with image)

Comment: What you want to use ListView or RecyclerView     ?

Comment: @sushantgosavi When user clicks on image it expands and shows text below the image. and the recyckerview is because i have dynamic data for the images and the collapsed text